# Download folder, not a single file

Tags: folder, downloads

There was one another question that was the same as mine but the answers were from 2010, so my question is: How can I download a folder as a whole and not a single file?
I want to download my music folder from another computer. Is that in any way possible?

Comment: I guess you need to specify "download". To you have an account on that other computer? Or just an internet adress? Which operating systems are involved?

Comment: From another computer but via what? FTP, SCP?

Comment: Btw... if you can download 1 file you can also zip your folder and download that file (since you made it into 1 file ;-) )

Answer (score 5):

Some methods (click the links for more information):

1. [ssh](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH)
2. [ftp](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ProFTPD?action=show&redirect=ProFTP)
3. [transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/) a torrent (with a [private tracker](http://bootstrike.com/Articles/CreateTorrent/))
4. [NFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/C/network-file-system.html) (mounting a directory).
5. [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/)
6. [Samba](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/samba-fileserver.html)
7. On-line services (U1, mediafire etc).

If you have acces to both machines NFS might be the best option.

Comment: You should add Samba :) (I know the other person mentioned it) with a link as well. BTW sorry I didn't vote - I have to wait 8hrs for a reset.

Comment: Samba is for the weak!

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways to accomplish this. One is to mount the remote directory. This can be done via samba shares (if the remote host is running windows this is quite simple). If the remote host is running Linux then you could either mount the remote directory using sshfs or simply connect to it with an FTP client such as filezilla (filezilla can be set to connect over ssh which is often simpler) and download the entire directory that way.

Answer (score 2):

Using command line utility scp (which requires openssh-server is installed on the remote system and openssh-client is installed on your system) you can copy a remote directory and all its files (and subdirectories), if you can log into that remote system with appropriate privileges, as follows:

Let's say you know, for the remote system, the ip address, a username/password, and the path to the folder on the system. Let's assume:

- ip address: 10.0.0.1
- remote username is: joe
- that user's password is joepassword
- the path to the folder on the remote system is /home/joe/thefolder

Top move that folder to your current drectory:

```
scp -r joe@10.0.01:/home/joe/thefolder .
```

Enter the password when prompted and the folder is copied.

Note the period (".") on the end, which means scp to the current directory